# How to successfully build and run pycdc?

Tags: c++

I have followed the directions on the pycdc GitHub, and followed various other stack overflow threads, and have been able to successfully build and run all of the projects in the pycdc directory on Visual Studio. However, I still cannot run the pycdc command to decompile a .pyc file. There is no bin directory where any executables are to be found. I am running on Windows 11.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works on windows and you need to install windows build tools using visual studio installer.
Make sure to install cmake tools.

clone the repo using `git clone https://github.com/zrax/pycdc.git`

Search and Open `Developer PowerShell for VS`

go to the cloned repository folder

use commands below

`cmake .`
`msbuild pycdc.sln`

the pycdc.exe will be created in the Debug folder.